# JavaScript add wordlist to each link

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a list of "words" let's say

```
var words=["aa","ab","ac","ad","ae"];
```

and then print out for each word a link.
So let's say my link is test.com/ and what I want to do is add each word to that link, but separately. So it would print out: `http://test.com/aa , http://test.com/ab ,  http://test.com/ac , http://test.com/ad, http://test.com/ae`

Comment: The code you supplied is javascript? in php, you can use a foreach loop. 

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Cool. Good luck! Do you have a question for us?

Comment: @Hallur Yes it's javascript. I'm going to try using foreach loop thanks :)

Comment: @Devon - You do realize that the link he posted is for, as he mentioned, PHP and not Javascript?

Comment: Either the tag has been changed from php to javascript or I forgot to type in [php] in the search q&a field. I apologize. Here's an example in javascript. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: @Hallur - It's changed

Comment: Any way I can fix href tag to make it "Test.test/ + word" ? http://hastebin.com/hacuqupewe.xml

Comment: @Hallur Could you help me with this? :)

Comment: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's not for homework, but I'll try to explain it better. So I got it working :  hastebin.com/hacuqupewe.xml   but I only can't figure out how to make each "link" have a href tag that links to it.     Currently what happens is it works perfectly, but when I click anything it will send me to Test.test instead of Test.test/aa , test.test/ab, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

By using the map constructor on the array, you can modify each item

```
words.map(function(val){
    return "http://test.com/" + val //Add http://test.com/ before each value in the array
})
```

Giving you the array of

```
 ["http://test.com/aa", "http://test.com/ab", "http://test.com/ac", "http://test.com/ad", "http://test.com/ae"]
```

So what map does is it takes each value in an array, runs a function, and returns  a value. This new value will replace the part of the array that was used. It is similar to forEach, but map is what you want to use in this case.